# Correct directory structure for adding code into bitbucket using Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, repository, bitbucket

I have a project repository here.  It houses more than just code.  It has a wiki and other documentation.

https://bitbucket.org/udfr/main/overview

Which directory should I commit the code into? There is a tab for source, which is this directory: https://bitbucket.org/udfr/main/src

Before putting the code there, I wanted to see if this is the right approach. I wanted to see how other people are using bitbucket for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The appropriate URL to be used for cloning, pushing, and pulling (basically all synchronization tasks) can be seen by clicking on the Source tab as shown below:
[image]

The Wiki is hosted in a different repository and can be accessed by appending a `/wiki` to the url shown above.

Also, these urls change based on which repository you have selected from the Repository pulldown menu.